# Python else block doesn't print anything

Tags: python, if-statement, error-handling

Here in this code else block is not printing the value `Treasure locked`

```
def counted(value):
    if(value == 5):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def numb(value1):
    sam = 95
    value = 0
    stp = 97
    h = {}
    for i in range(0,26):
        h.update({chr(stp) : (ord(chr(stp))-sam)})
        sam = sam-1
        stp = stp+1
    for j in range(0,5):
        value = h[value1[j]]+value

    if(value > 80):
        print('First lock-unlocked')
    else:
        print('Treasure locked')

string = input()
firstcheck = counted(len(string))
if(firstcheck == 1):
    numb(string)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`else` block is working properly. if you want to print Treasure Locked. you have to pass lower character `string` like `'aaaaa'`. if `value` is `>` `80`. then it always print `First lock-unlocked`.

Answer (score 1):

a good idea is to check what the condition is before entering the if statements, possibly check what `value` is printing before the if statement. the logic in `def numb()` has very little do with what's in `def counted()`. as long as one is `1` or `0` is being passed to `numb()` we know that function will run and seems like it.